# Error: ORA-12154 SQL Server Link Server with Oracle 11g in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, windows-server-2012

I need to create Link Server in SQL Server 2012 Enterprise 64 using Oracle ODAC.

I have done everything I know, including multiple re-installation of Windows Server 2012 Standard R2 64. The ODAC is also 64bit.

I am able to connect to Oracle 11g using Oracle SQL Developer using TNS as Connection Type.

I am beginning to think this may have something to do with Windows Server. Because I have never experience this issue on other systems *not* running Windows Server.

I get this error:

*returned message "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After combining through hundreds of internet posts and install/reinstall. I discovered the problem was the ORACLE ODAC Components. Every article on the internet tells you to install 64bit ODAC if you are running 64bit database, however, this is not accurate.

After spending two days trying to get this to work, I decided to try the 32bit ODAC and it worked.

In case anyone is having this same issue.